# Change slides' field in presentation with pyhton

Tags: python, replace, slide, presentation

I have an excel file and I would like to use these items to replace my slides, I added ABC code to replace my presentation but I can reach the title but cannot reach to paragraph.

Could you please explain how I can reach to paragraph and replace it in my presentation?

For example:

myexcel.xlsx

- FirstName LastName  Sex
- Tim       Knight    Man

---

mypresentation.pptx

Slide 1

- Title (ABC)
- Body (The first name is ABC)

Slide 2

- Body (The last name is ABC )

---

**Result**:

Slide 1

- Man
- The first name is Tim

Slide 2

- The last name is Knight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `openpyxl` for the Excel and `python-pptx` for the presentation:

```
import openpyxl
from pptx import Presentation

ex = "myexcel.xlsx"
pr = "mypresentation.pptx"

# Excel with openpyxl
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(ex)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
max_row = sheet_obj.max_row
max_col = sheet_obj.max_column

column_list = []
row_list = []

for ro in range(1, max_row + 1):
    for co in range(1, max_col + 1):
        if ro == 1:
            cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = ro, column = co)
            column_list.append(cell_obj.value)
        if ro > 1:
            cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = ro, column = co)
            row_list.append(cell_obj.value)
print("Column Names:", column_list)
print("Row text", row_list)

# Presentation with python-pptx; https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
prs=Presentation(pr)
text_runs = []
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_text_frame:
            continue
        for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                text_runs.append(run.text)
                #print(run.text)
                if run.text == "Title (ABC)":
                    run.text = row_list[2]
                if run.text == "Body (The first name is ABC)":
                    run.text = "The first name is "+row_list[0]
                if run.text == "Body (The last name is ABC)":
                    run.text = "The last name is "+row_list[1]
            prs.save('new.pptx')
            
print("Text written in new.pptx")                    
print("Text in old slides:",text_runs)
```

Output, see file **"new.ppt"**:

```
Column Names: ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Sex']
Row text ['Tim', 'Knight', 'Man']
Text written in new.pptx
Text in old slides: ['Slide 1', 'Title (ABC)', 'Body (The first name is ABC)', 'Slide 2', 'Body (The last name is ABC)']
```

Comment: Hi @herman12, I used Replacer for ABC place and give different codes for each ABC. By the way, the Title and Body are not words, they are placed in the presentation. There is a title and body you write your sentences but even that it works thank u :)

Comment: Please accept my answer, if this was helpful. You have to share more information , if you expect more detailed answers, and share your code,please. On the other side it should be easy to adjust my example for your needs. Slide1 is the title text.